# resolving messages with arguments

Tags: grails

I've noticed some strange behaviour when resolving Grails messages using the `g.message` tag. In my properties file I've defined this message:

```
deleted={0} has been deleted
```

If I resolve this with:

```
Long id = 1878L
message(code: 'festival.deleted', args: [id.toString()])
```

the result is:

> 1878 has been deleted

which is what I would have expected. However, if I resolve it with:

```
Long id = 1878L
message(code: 'festival.deleted', args: [id])
```

the result is:

> 1,878 has been deleted

It's not clear to me why the number is formatted as "1,878" before it's substituted into the message. I thought perhaps `toString()` is called on all message arguments if they're not already of type `String`, but this doesn't appear to explain this behaviour, because

```
id.toString() == "1878"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `g.message` tag uses Java's [MessageFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) to generate the text output. MessageFormat has several default ways of formatting arguments if no argument format is specified. `{0} has been deleted` says there's an argument but doesn't say how to format it.

If the argument is a String, the string is inserted into the message. If the argument is a Number, [NumberFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) is used.

```
groovy:000> NumberFormat.getInstance().format(1878L)
===> 1,878
```

There's a nice table in the docs for [`format()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html#format%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.text.FieldPosition%29) that breaks down what happens in what cases. If you want to use a Long as your argument without calling `toString()` on it, you can change your argument to `{0,number,#}` which would be equivalent to

```
groovy:000> new DecimalFormat("#", DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance()).format(1878L)
===> 1878
```

Comment: I had no idea you could include formatting info in the argument placeholder, thanks!

Comment: You forgot to mention the importance of `Locale` here. `NumberFormat.getInstance()` uses default locale. For UK and US the number format is same (1,878). Change the locale to French (in taglib), you would see the difference in number format. SO, it is the locale which drives the format not just the `NumberFormat`. @Dónal